# What are all the triads of Greek mythology?

Tags: greek

There are the big three: Hades, Poseidon, Zeus. Furthermore, the Fates, the Furies, the judges of the Underworld, the elder Cyclopes, the Hecatoncheires and the Oneiroi.

There are also three rules of the universe: the [Primordials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_primordial_deities), the [Titans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(mythology)), and the [Olympians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twelve_Olympians).

I am writing a book and **three** seems to be a theme in Greek mythology. Any other groups of three would be helpful.

Comment: Sons of Kronos and Rhea, daughters of Kronos and Rhea, Graces, Gorgons, claimants of the Apple of Discord, Old Men of the Sea (Nereus, Phorkys, Proteus) . . . on Furies, I consider *Eumenides,* wherein they are a whole chorus, to be the Greek *locus classicus,* but if one goes by Virgil they are three too.  Then there seems to be some rather mysterious three-ness involving Hecate. But the concernancy, sir? Why do we wrap these triads in our more rawer breath?

Comment: Possibly you could massage this question to make it more directly answerable.  I think asking about triads in Greek mythology in general might be more acceptable to the general community.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitively answering the question of "how many" would require an enormous research effort, and it's a little fuzzy in terms of what qualifies.  Being lazy, I only say triads are important and quite common.

I suggest taking a look at:

- [Tripartite Goddess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_deity#Triple_goddesses)

It lists manifestations such as the Boeotian [three muses configuration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muses#Number_and_names) ([Melete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Melete), [Aoide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aoide) and [Mneme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mneme), which legendarily pre-dates the nine muses.

Maiden/Mother/Crone configurations are particularly prevalent, for instance [Kore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persephone)/[Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demeter)/[Rhea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhea_(mythology)). (The prevalence of female triads relates to the three distinct biological conditions related to reproduction--pre-pubescent, fertile, and menopausal. Pagan religions tend to be preoccupied with cycles of generation.)

Among the most famous triads are:

- The [Morai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moirai) (Three Fates)
- The [Charites](http://Charites) (Three Graces)
- The [Horae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horae) (Seasons)

More fearsome famous triads are:

- The [Erinyes/Eumenides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erinyes) (Furies/Kindly Ones)
- The [Gorgons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgon)
- The [Sirens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siren_(mythology))

And of course:

- The [Hesperides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hesperides) ("Daughters of the Evening")
- The [Graeae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graeae) (Known for sharing a single eye between them)
- The [Oenotropae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oenotropae) ("The Winegrowers")

A famous tri-partite male figure is

- [Triptolemus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triptolemus)

Although it's important to recognize his connection to Demeter and the [Eleusinian Mysteries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eleusinian_Mysteries).

- Achilles/[Patroclus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patroclus)/Hector

Is an important triad, where the fates of the three warriors are entwined.

- The [riddle of the Sphinx (Oedipus)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oedipus#Basics_of_the_myth)

In this famous version of the riddle, "the creature that goes on four legs in the morning, two legs in the day, and three legs at night" is an an analogy for the three phases of human life: childhood, adulthood, old age.